# Vertical score positioning in LilyPond

Tags: notation, drums, lilypond

I'm writing a drum sheet template for LilyPond and I'd like to place a drum key box to the left of the header. Here is what I've done so far:

[image: Drum sheet template on LilyPond]
*LilyBin link for fiddling with my markup: http://lilybin.com/yx9viw/1*

The problem I'd like to solve is vertically positioning the `score` or the `DrumStaff` inside the box, to remove all the blank space at the top. I figure removing the `Stem_engraver` would help (and is also desirable, since I only want to show the note heads in the drum key), but it doesn't really work (see line 63 on LilyBin), and while `\hide`-ing the stems does work, it doesn't eliminate the vertical space occupied by them.

So, does anyone know how I can:

1. *Remove* (not hide) the stem engraver from the score inside the `\box` (line 60 on LilyBin), and
2. Vertically position the entire score so it stays at the top of the `\box`, thus eliminating all that whitespace?

Comment: If you use \omit Stem instead of \hide Stem, you will get rid of the stems (and they won't take up any space), but I have no idea about what is making that whitespace. Nor why the stems are rendered when Stem_engraver is removed...

Comment: @Ramillies thank you, I didn't know the `\omit` function =). Eliminating the stems I figured the whitespace is generated by the `\markup` texts I use to label the note heads. Even when I override the `TextScript` position using `#'extra-offset`, the text leaves behind the whitespace it should have occupied without the override. (http://lilybin.com/yx9viw/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, is there any reason why you have the markups with the labels connected to invisible notes on the left and the right? Why not just put it in a line like this: http://lilybin.com/yx9viw/4 .

What I did is `\box { \line { \raise #something \left \score { ... } \raise #something \right } }`. It works OK it seems. (The `#something`'s were chosen to make the labels match with the note columns.)

(This is better because you can `\raise` the labels into the right places (this command generally works only for moving a part of markup relative to the rest of the markup).)

Comment: I used invisible notes because I didn't know any better =) Thank you so much, this is a cleaner solution than I was expecting for LilyPond, and the knowledge that the `\line` function can contain whole `\score`s opens up a lot of possibilities!

Comment: @nunks.lol: Yeah, the markup system is very general and powerful. `\line` just grabs some markups and puts them into a line :—). And a markup can contain `\score` (it's "just" a markup command in the same way as e. g. `\italic` is). (Maybe you can see why I like Lilypond so much? :—))